# Заполнение нескольких html-элементов, найденных по id

Tags: javascript, html, dom

есть такой код

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("line-chart1").getContext("2d");
    window.weightChart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: lineChartData,
        options: lineChartOptions,
    });
    document.getElementById("line-chart-legend").innerHTML = weightChart1.generateLegend();
```

он ловит первый ид и на этом останавливается, а мне нужно, чтобы он заполнил все найденные ид

Comment: id уникальны, поэтому находится только один элемент.

Comment: ид дива, а у меня таблица

Comment: ну и что что у тебя таблица? id все равно **уникальный** на странице. и будет находиться только **один** элемент

Comment: вот, почитай  https://webref.ru/html/attr/id, будет полезно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("line-chart1").getContext("2d");
    window.weightChart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: lineChartData,
        options: lineChartOptions,
    });
    var aElem=document.querySelectorAll("#line-chart-legend");
for(i=0;i<aElem.length;i++){
   aElem[i].innerHTML = weightChart1.generateLegend();
}
```